# The opacity change animation in jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, opacity

I have an issue with the jQuery animation. I have an element that should:
(1) change its opacity from 0 to 1 and slide down in the same time
(2) and then shrink from 100% height to 5px height
when is mouse over its parent and go back when the mouse is out of the parent.
Everything works except the very first animation which is opacity change. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
var $menu_it = jQuery('.menu-item');
$menu_it.append('<span class="menu_item_bar"></span>');
$menu_it.mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true,true).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 100);
    jQuery(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true,true).animate({"bottom":"25px"}, 100);
    jQuery(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true,true).delay(100).animate({"height":"5px"}, 500);
});
$menu_it.mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true,true).animate({"height":"100%"}, 500, function(){
        jQuery(this).stop(true,true).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
    });
    jQuery(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true,true).animate({"bottom":"190px"}, 750);
});
```

And here's jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sg5db8y1/21/
Thank you in advance for yor help.
PS There's jQuery instead of $ sign cause I have to do this in Wordpress enviroment.

Comment: in `fiddle` code working properly

Comment: everything is working fine except the fact that there's no fadein-like effect at the beginning of the animation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you repeatedly call `stop(true, true)` as you define each animation. This means that you're ending the previously defined animation (which only just started) and move it to its final position.

To fix this, don't call `stop()` when defining successive animations, or better still, define all animations in the same call:

```js
var $menu_it = $('.menu-item');
$menu_it.append('<span class="menu_item_bar"></span>');

$menu_it.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true, true).animate({
    "opacity": "1",
    "bottom": "25px",
    "height": "5px"
  }, 500);
});

$menu_it.mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find('.menu_item_bar').stop(true, true).animate({
    "height": "100%",
    "opacity": "0",
    "bottom": "190px"
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
body .menu-item {
  padding: 50px 25px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item a {
  padding-bottom: 86px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
}

.menu_item_bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 2</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 3</a>
</div>
```

That being said, you can make this much more effectively using CSS only:

```css
body .menu-item {
  padding: 50px 25px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item a {
  padding-bottom: 86px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu_item_bar {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: 25px;
}

.menu_item_bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, bottom 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
  <span class="menu_item_bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 2</a>
  <span class="menu_item_bar"></span>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">
  <a href="#">Menu item 3</a>
  <span class="menu_item_bar"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answer, it's very helpful. Using pure CSS is much better in this example. I asked also because I have to do similar animation later using scrollTop which cannot be obtained using CSS only. Anyway, thank you again for your kind help!

Comment: Also note that you could still utilise CSS animation by adding/removing a class on the element when you scroll instead of using JS animations which can be perform poorly.